# How this object work on addEventListener method in following code?

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxykb6d9/7/)

I have following Html code :

```
<table id="outside">
    <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
</table>
```

and Js code :

```
var el = document.getElementById("outside");
var Something = function(element) {
  this.name = 'Something Good';
  this.onclick1 = function(event) {
    console.log(this.name); // undefined, as this is the element
  };
  this.onclick2 = function(event) {
    console.log(this.name); // 'Something Good'
  };
  el.addEventListener('click', this.onclick1, false);
  el.addEventListener('click', this.onclick2.bind(this), false); 
}
Something();
```

while execution of `Something()`, `this` refer to the `Window` object. so `onclick1` and `onclick2` is the method on `Window` object.

**Doubt :**

1. When `el.addEventListener('click', this.onclick1, false);` is executed `this` object  in  `this.onclick1` refer to the `el` object. then why `onclick1` method is called(which is a method of `window` object), when an event is triggred.`onclick1` method should call on `window` object not on `el` object.
2. In `el.addEventListener('click', this.onclick2.bind(this), false);`How  `this` object in `this.onclick2` and `onclick2.bind(this)` is different?

This example is taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are passed the element of the event target as the `this` object.

`Function.bind()` forces the `this` object of the called function to be a particular object, the parameter to bind.

If you don't override `this` with `fn.bind(thisObject)` when you create the handler function, then it will default to the event target (as mentioned in the MDN link in your question).  If you do, it will be whichever object you specified as a parameter to `.bind()`.

Additional info about `.bind()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind